# Grammaticality of "Is it today that..."

Tags: grammaticality, questions, sentence-starts, dummy-it

I would like to know if it is grammatically correct to ask the question, "Is it today that you are going to town?" My concern is specifically the "Is it" part.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly grammatical. It's a typical [cleft sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence).

Comment: Or more technically, a yes/no question formed from an _it_-cleft sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler A dichotomous interrogatory *it*-cleft sentence?

Comment: All clefts are dichotomous; they split a sentence like _You are going to town today_ into two parts, which balance on each side of the fulcrum of cleavage, which is usually some form of _be_.